# Unable to get Dojo custom module working with ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, dojo

New to Dojo and I am just trying to get a basic Hello world module working in dojo/MVC and can't seem to get it to work. I keep getting either

> no response / errors at all or cryptic Syntax errors in dojo.js e()
>   h.injectUrl/h()

is what it says when using FireFox / Firebug.
I am using 1.8 and have tried both the CDN and local copies.

Here is the code below.

**Index.cshtml**

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script><script>
    // Require default stuff and new module
    require([
                "~/Scripts/dojoDemo/newModule"
    ],
    function (newModule) {
        newModule.setText("greetings", "Hello peoples");
        settimeout(function () {
            newModule.restoreText("greeting");
        }, 3000);
    });</script><h1 id="greetings">What up</h1>

<br/>
<br/>
```

**newModule.js**

```
define([
    // Define the dependencies
    "dojo/dom"], 
    // Create this function to call new module
    function (dom) {
        var oldText = {};
        return {
            setText: function (id, text) {
                var node = dom.byId(id);
                oldText[id] = node.innerHTML;
                node.innerHTML = text;
            },
            restoreText: function (id) {
                var node = dom.byId(id);
                node.innerHTML = oldText[id];
                delete oldText;
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the path to the module in the dojo config and not the `require` call. `paths` map the top level module name to where the files are located to the server.  By default, the file path is relative to dojo.js

```
<script src="~/Scripts/dojo/dojo.js" 
  data-dojo-config="async: true, isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true, 
     paths: { dojoDemo: '../dojoDemo' }">
</script>
<script>
  require(["dojoDemo/newModule", "dojo/domReady!"], function (newModule) {
      newModule.setText("greeting", "Hello peoples");
      setTimeout(function () {
          newModule.restoreText("greeting");
      }, 3000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent Craig. Now I'm getting into the module, but on the var node = dom.byId(id), I am getting node as undefined. Basically it is not seeing the h1 tag with the id of 'greetings'. I did a break in the module to make sure that it is greetings that is being passed in. There is a missspelling in my example above not adding the 's' on greetings. that is fixed and it is still not finding it. Thanks again

Comment: Try requiring "dojo/domReady!".  See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/domReady.html

Comment: "dojo/ready" is something you will want to know about as well. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/ready.html